# Do I have to license Google Design Guidelines to implement them as best practices?

Tags: business, legal, licensing

I really like google's approach  in design, it's clean and simple.I want to use their guidelines in one of my up coming projects (which is quite a big one).

what is the legal status for using google's [design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design) in your application design? under what licence are they released ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can produce whatever you want from the guidelines, that's what guidelines are. If you copy their exact graphics that's another story but if you're just using it as inspiration and guidance for your own ideas its perfectly legal.

Its like if I read a tutorial on best html practices by Smashingmag, and then implement those practices. I don't owe Smashingmag a royalty. Or if someone comes to our site and reads a tutorial on how to make Gummy Worms, then goes off and makes Gummy Worms - they don't owe us a royalty.